# How do I get a certificate from the secure store service?

Tags: secure-store

I've added a certificate (pfx file, Google API) to the secure store in SharePoint 2013. How do I retrieve it using c#? I know how to retrieve any other string from the secure store but everything I have tried to get the  certificate results in an invalid byte array.

Also I've used Reflector on the SecureStringHelper class and tried using the GetBytes method but it does not seem to work.